# panda to_csv set column order when columns are missing occasionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm using panda to convert json data to csv, but I want the column to be in certain order. Now, sometimes in the json data, some columns dont exist. so, this is what I use so far:

```
cols = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(json)).to_csv(columns=cols)
```

sometimes, if `d` doesnt exist, it would complain `request failed because [d] is not in index`. is there a way to make panda ignore non existing column but still maintain the column order?
btw, json contains nested object, but only 1 child level max.

so, in case of missing column, the column order should still be `a,b,c,d,e,f`, just the value of all rows will be empty for the missing columns.
Example if `b` and `d` is missing, then:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
one,,three,,five,six
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen if d is missing?

Comment: @artemis keep the column order as `a,b,c,d,e,f` but all rows will be empty for column `d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```py
cols = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(json))
df.reindex(columns=cols).to_csv()
```

If instead you want just the column that are in `df`, but in the order of `cols`:

```py
df.to_csv(columns=[k for k in cols if k in df.columns])
```

Example (using on of [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) examples):

```py
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cole Volk",
        "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60},
    },
    {"name": "Mark Reg", "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60}},
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Faye Raker",
        "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60},
    },
]
df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=1)

>>> df
    id        name  fitness.height  fitness.weight
0  1.0   Cole Volk             130              60
1  NaN    Mark Reg             130              60
2  2.0  Faye Raker             130              60
```

Then:

```py
cols = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'fitness.height', 'fitness.weight']
print(df.reindex(columns=cols).to_csv())

,id,name,age,fitness.height,fitness.weight
0,1.0,Cole Volk,,130,60
1,,Mark Reg,,130,60
2,2.0,Faye Raker,,130,60
```

Notice the column `'age'` is not present in that `df`, so the column in the CSV is empty.

Comment: so, for this, I need the column header to stay `a,b,c,d,e,f` but the value of all rows will be empty for the missing columns. will reindex achieve this? Thanks

Comment: example for `b,c` missing -> 

a,b,c,d,e,f

one,,,four,five,six

Comment: Yes. See edited answer with an example.

Comment: yes, this looks good. let me try when I'm back in my PC. if this works, I'll accept your answer. Thanks